# Android restart application on configuration change

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, android-webview, flags

Hi in my application i am loading local html pages in my webview ,this html pages will load based on the locale or language selected , these pages also have values which i pass dynamically using JS ,but when i am changing the language, i am unable to change the dynamical values so i thought to restart the application if there is configuration change no matter in what screen i am. The application should start from scratch that is splash screen .How can i achieve this. Go code to restart the app, but is it correct way

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                 .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: You can create a service and generate a broadcast when exiting application. The receiver must be written in the service which will start your activity when broadcast is received.

Comment: @JibranKhan hi can u please elobarate on it

Comment: Do you have idea about services and broadcasting in Android ?

Answer (score 0):

```
        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
```

this is the which works for me. i have a splashscreen before MainActivity and is works fine..